# Easy Git Starter for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I really need to understand how to use git on Windows, but all the guides are too complex. For example, I understand we need to use a command line for git. But when I open a command prompt in Windows using "cmd.exe", where do I go? Do I navigate to the folder where git is installed? What is "git bash"?

Why do all the examples on the Internet have this $ sign in front? How do I add an existing folder to git version control? What does "checkout" mean? I keep hearing about a tool called "powershell". What does it do and how is it different from a DOS prompt?

To use the "git" command I'll probably have to add it to my environment variables so the computer can find it and I get "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I've never used a version control system for my programming before - I've just saved folders with numbers in front of them so far and I need to use git to publish a project folder I have on Amazon AWS Beanstalk.

I basically just want to add a folder to git and save changes regularly so I have a back up of all the stuff I've done before.

Edit: Is git a single program, or are there many "gits". The first result for "git" in google takes me here: http://git-scm.com/ and yet lots of people talk about something called "msysgit". Is this a different git application?

Edit: I'm looking more at a command line for Windows tutorial. It's here that I'm having the most trouble.

Comment: The very first result on a Google search of `git tutorial windows` looks promising; so do the next four or five below the first.

Comment: If you want to understand how Git works (regardless of operating system), pour yourself a cup of tea, grab a biscuit and watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwIwi80bXX4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand some of the concepts of Git (and only then you can use it effectively), you should read the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) (available online and for download, or even to buy on paper). This is a really good book, teaching you the very basics you need with good examples, and having sections on more advanced stuff if you want to know more.

The book assumes that you use a Unix-/Linux-like shell (like Bash). Msysgit (a.k.a. "Git for Windows") brings Bash with it, pre-configured for easy use of Git. (And no, there are not many gits, Msysgit is just a bundle that brings some other dependencies of Git which are not usually installed on Windows.)

A shell (also named console or terminal) is in this case a command-line interpreter, just like cmd.exe is on Windows; on the *nix-like systems, there are many more alternatives than on Windows (where one alternative is Powershell), but that's just some side info here.

The $ sign in the examples you see is a typical prompt delimiter on *nix-like shells; on Windows (cmd.exe), you usually have ">" as the delimiter. It has no special meaning and just serves as a delimiter.

What "checkout" means and how you add files and folders to version control, is explained very well in the mentioned book. You also do not need to know anything about version control in general, the book is really written for absolute beginners (in fact, to start using Git it might be an advantage not to know other VCSs).

If you need any help with the stuff that's in the book (or in other tutorials mentioned there, here, or on Google), feel free to drop by the #git IRC channel (more info on the [git-scm.com community page](http://git-scm.com/community), where people can help you immediately and with small questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of tutorials that worked for me:

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=git+windows&oq=git+windows&gs_l=youtube.3...250.879.0.972.7.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.1.

They show you how to install the various components and then how to use Git with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Github* has GUI application for [Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (as well as for [Mac](http://mac.github.com/)) which is pretty friendly to novices. You won't get a lot of insight, but this might help you to get up and running.

*git-repository hosting, e.g. place where you can store your repos and sync with them from time to time. It's free and awesome.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus you have approved the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4127563) that removes my passage which said that you can only work with github repositories. Do you have evidence that you can use github windows application to work with generic git projects other than local? (e.g. can I use it for bitbucket?). Otherwise, you did a pretty bad job as a reviewer.